# How to create a field validation for TextBlob in JHipster v5.0 (using JDL)?

Tags: jhipster

I want to know why `Jhipster v5` does not like `TextBlob` fields validations and what is the substitute (for `TextBlob`, if we should use other) now?

```
entity Comment {
    creationDate Instant required
    commentText TextBlob minbytes(3) maxbytes(5000) required
    isOffensive Boolean
}

Hibernate JPA 2 Metamodel does not work with Bean Validation 2 for LOB fields, so LOB validation is disabled
WARNING! Cannot use validation in .jhipster/Comment.json for field {
"fieldName": "commentText",
"fieldType": "byte[]",
"fieldTypeBlobContent": "text",
"fieldValidateRules": [
"minbytes",
"maxbytes",
"required"
],
"fieldValidateRulesMinbytes": 3,
"fieldValidateRulesMaxbytes": 5000
}
```

This worked fine in `version 4.13`.

Comment: If it was working in JH4 and no longer works in JH5 , you should rather open an issue on github

Comment: Thanks Gäel, it is done https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/7842